# In Java, how to find if first character in a string is upper case without regex

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, char

In Java, find if the first character in a string is upper case without using regular expressions.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Assuming `s` is non-empty:

```
Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(0))
```

or, as mentioned by [divec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665348/283837), to make it work for characters with code points above `U+FFFF`:

```
Character.isUpperCase(s.codePointAt(0));
```

Answer (score 44):

Actually, this is subtler than it looks.

The code above would give the incorrect answer for a lower case character whose code point was above U+FFFF (such as U+1D4C3, MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL N). String.charAt would return a UTF-16 surrogate pair, which is not a character, but rather half the character, so to speak. So you have to use String.codePointAt, which returns an int above 0xFFFF (not a char). You would do:

```
Character.isUpperCase(s.codePointAt(0));
```

Don't feel bad overlooked this; almost all Java coders handle UTF-16 badly, because the terminology misleadingly makes you think that each "char" value represents a character. UTF-16 sucks, because it is almost fixed width but not quite. So non-fixed-width edge cases tend not to get tested. Until one day, some document comes in which contains a character like U+1D4C3, and your entire system blows up.

Comment: How do you guys know all this. I mean , where do you learn these things. Generally a programming course don't have these deep knowledge stuffs.

Answer (score 6):

There is many ways to do that, but the simplest seems to be the following one:

```
boolean isUpperCase = Character.isUpperCase("My String".charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check whether the string is empty or `null`. If we forget checking `null` or empty then we would get `NullPointerException` or `StringIndexOutOfBoundException` if a given String is null or empty.

```
public class StartWithUpperCase{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            String str1 = ""; //StringIndexOfBoundException if 
                              //empty checking not handled
            String str2 = null; //NullPointerException if 
                                //null checking is not handled.
            String str3 = "Starts with upper case";
            String str4 = "starts with lower case";

            System.out.println(startWithUpperCase(str1)); //false
            System.out.println(startWithUpperCase(str2)); //false
            System.out.println(startWithUpperCase(str3)); //true
            System.out.println(startWithUpperCase(str4)); //false



        }

        public static boolean startWithUpperCase(String givenString){

            if(null == givenString || givenString.isEmpty() ) return false;
            else return (Character.isUpperCase( givenString.codePointAt(0) ) );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you first check for null and empty and ten converts existing string to upper. Use S.O.P if want to see outputs otherwise boolean like Rabiz did.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     System.out.println("Enter name");
     Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
     String text =  kb.next();

     if ( null == text || text.isEmpty())
     {
         System.out.println("Text empty");
     }
     else if (text.charAt(0) == (text.toUpperCase().charAt(0)))
     {
         System.out.println("First letter in word "+ text + " is upper case");
     }
  }
```

Comment: I think this will tell you that '3' is upper case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check it out manually you can do `int a = s.charAt(0)`

If the value of a is between 65 to 90 it is upper case.

Comment: What about non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "yadayada";
if (Character.isUpperCase(yourString.charAt(0))) {
    // print something
} else {
    // print something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can find upper case letter by using regular expression as well

```
private static void findUppercaseFirstLetterInString(String content) {
    Matcher m = Pattern
            .compile("([a-z])([a-z]*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(
                    content);
    System.out.println("Given input string : " + content);
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group(1).equals(m.group(1).toUpperCase())) {
            System.out.println("First Letter Upper case match found :"
                    + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

for detailed example . please visit http://www.onlinecodegeek.com/2015/09/how-to-determines-if-string-starts-with.html