# Comparing characters

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following code:

```
String myString = "Hello";
char firstChar = myString.charAt(0);
```

I then want to check if firstChar has value "B". I tried

```
if(myChar == "b")
```

and

```
if(myChar.equals("b"))
```

but none of these work.

What solution could I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`"b"` is not char but string to compare char you should write `if(myChar == 'b')`

Note:

```
5   means number 
'5' means char 
"5" means string
```

all are different datatypes.

read: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

`==` compares reference equality.  and `.equals()` tests for value equality.

read also this to check for upper or lower char: [Find if first character in a string is upper case, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452939/find-if-first-character-in-a-string-is-upper-case-java)

Comment: @DarioPanada see right hand side of this page **Related**, All are useful for you. Also when you type a question you will find related questions which can save your time to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'B'. Java is case sensitieve, and you neer to compare a `char` instead of `String`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the char literal by ':

```
if(myChar == 'b')
```

quotes(") represent strings. apostrophes(') represent characters

Answer (score 0):

Characters work differently than `String`.  You can't call methods on them, but you *can* compare them using `==`.

If you want to compare either case, then you can use this:

```
if(myChar == 'b' || myChar == 'B')
```