# Check if a certain char is a certain letter java

Tags: java, string, char

I'm working in coding bat and one of the questions requires me to check if a certain char in a string is a certain letter. Then it returns an error:

```
Error:  if (starttwochars.charAt(0) == "o")
Incompatible operand types char and String
```

Here is my code:

```
public String startOz(String str) {
  String starttwochars = str.substring(0,1);
  if (starttwochars.charAt(0) == "o"){
    if (starttwochars.charAt(1) == "z") {
      return "oz";
    }

    else {
      return "o";
    }
  }

  else {
    if (starttwochars.charAt(1) == "z") {
      return "z";
    }

    else {
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me how I'm supposed to see if the certain char is the string. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a char literal, not a string literal: `== 'o'`.

Comment: double quotes `"o"` are used for Strings and single quotes `'o'` are used for char

Comment: Perfect dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15992110/1743880. Goldies, to your hammer :)!

Comment: Oh! Thanks it worked

Comment: Try `Character.isLetter`.

Comment: Note also: `str.substring(0,1)` has 1 character (the second parameter is exclusive). You'd need to use `str.substring(0,2)` to get the first two. But it's actually just easier to use `char first = str.charAt(0), second = str.charAt(1);`.